# Can you extend Cookie Duration for Login in BC?

Tags: cookies, authentication, business-catalyst

Can you extend Cookie Duration for Login in Business Catalyst?

As you can see the [Docs](http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/reference/misc/bc-cookies.html) say they last for 30 minutes and I have a client with a checkout which requires a longer time to go through.

There is no official way to extend it (in settings).

I was just wondering if there is a workaround to this cookie for visitors on the website? I know very little regarding cookies.

Answer (score 2):

This is a late reply but posting in case anyone else finds this question searching for answers.

You can force the cookie to have a lifetime of 1 year if you include a checkbox like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" id="RememberMe">
```

Comment: Do you know how to extend the cookie when you login with Facebook?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't.